# How to block an ip range in Firewalld

Tags: centos, firewalld

I know I can use the below command to block a single ip:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='115.239.228.12' reject"
```

but I need to block all ips starting from 115.239.x.x

I am having Cent os 7.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used firewalld, but have you simply tried providing a cidr specification?  `115.239.0.0/16`?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. It's the first thing I would try.

Comment: @Zoredache And [you are right](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html#Using_the_Rich_Rule_Log_Command_Example_3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not a user of firewalld myself, but for most firewall implementations, particularly linux-based ones, whenever you see the option for a source or destination address you can simply provide a CIDR style network specification.  So `115.239.0.0/16`.